# How to change the position of tab bar icon for ipad in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tabbar

I have some custom design with tab bar and I have almost achieved my custom design but in ipad it's not working as my custom button is not center aligned even label is also not center aligned. In fact the whole layout is changed in ipad, in iphone layout is shown in vertical stack but in ipad layout is shown in horizontal stack but for my custom button I want it in center aligned same as iphone but only for middle bar item. For this I am thinking to change the position of the button and label in case of ipad, I want to give margin from left but how would I achieve this no idea. If anybody knows the solution please help me out.

tab bar controller class

```
import UIKit
import SwiftIcons

class HomeViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        
        let selectedColor   = UIColor(red: 16.0/255.0, green: 78.0/255.0, blue: 91.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let unselectedColor = UIColor(red: 16.0/255.0, green: 224.0/255.0, blue: 223.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: unselectedColor], for: .normal)
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: selectedColor], for: .selected)
        
            
        //store every image in a variable
        
        let userUnselectedImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "add_workout_icon")!.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        let userSelectedImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "add_workout_icon")!.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        
            tabBar.items![2].image = userUnselectedImage
            tabBar.items![2].selectedImage = userSelectedImage
        
    }
    
}
```

iphone image
[image: iphone image]

ipad image: issue
[image: ipad image]

Comment: You could check whether or not the device is an iPad, like this: `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad`, and then position the items accordingly.

Comment: there is a major issue as well my custom button tap event is not working for upper part can you please help in tit